# In tableau desktop, graphs don't show on sheets, but same display fine on dashboards

Tags: tableau-desktop

This is for all graphs. Whatever graph I create, sheets display blank space. But when I add a sheet to dashboard, graph looks fine and works fine. On sheet, it is still missing. What could be the problem.

Update: If I export a sheet as picture, graph is there as well. But sheet shows nothing in case of map and only axis in case of other charts.

Comment: share a tableau public link of your work

Answer (score 0):

You might have changed the format(color) of your sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Could not find the problem. After a while, uninstalled everything. Downloaded fresh copy and installed it back. Worked fine. Same reports worked fine too.